# why are stop_words not supported in Elasticsearch 0.90 more_like_this_field query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Contrary to the current ES documentation http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-field-query.html, stop_words is an unsupported field for more_like_this_field queries in my ES installation.

```
version: 0.90.5
build_hash: c8714e8e0620b62638f660f6144831792b9dedee
build_timestamp: 2013-09-17T12:50:20Z
build_snapshot: false
lucene_version: 4.4
```

can anyone confirm this?

This is what I am sending to the server

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match_all": {
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "more_like_this_field": {
                        "FieldA": {
                            "like_text": "House",
                            "boost": 1,
                            "min_doc_freq": 0,
                            "min_word_len": 0,
                            "min_term_freq": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "more_like_this_field": {
                        "Equipped": {
                            "like_text": "pool garage",
                            "boost": 0,
                            "min_doc_freq": 0,
                            "min_word_len": 0,
                            "min_term_freq": 0,
                            "stop_words": "garden"
                        }

                    }
                },
                {
                    "more_like_this_field": {
                        "Neighbourhood": {
                            "like_text": "school",
                            "boost": 5,
                            "min_doc_freq": 0,
                            "min_word_len": 0,
                            "min_term_freq": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match": 2
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I get back

```
QueryParsingException[[data] [mlt_field] query does not support [stop_words]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same happens with the `more_like_this` query, the reason is that `stop_words` must be an array.

```
{
    "more_like_this_field": {
        "Equipped": {
            "like_text": "pool garage",
            "boost": 0,
            "min_doc_freq": 0,
            "min_word_len": 0,
            "min_term_freq": 0,
            "stop_words": ["garden"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would have to setup a java environment for that... so, no :)